# Listening to another window resize events in C#

Tags: c#, resize, hook

I am implementing a small application (observer) that needs to "attach" itself to the bottom of another window (observed). The latter is not a window inside the application.

At this moment I solved by getting the hWnd of the window and querying periodically in a thread the location of the observed window, moving the observer window accordingly.

However this is a very inelegant solution. What I would like to do is to listen to the resize event of the observed window so that the observer will react only when necessary.

I assume I should use a hook, and I found plenty of ways of doing it, but my lack of knowledge of the C WinAPI is blocking me in understanding which hook I need to create and how (pinvoke/parameters/etc).

I'm pretty sure this is quite trivial, and some of you familiar with C/C++ and WinAPI will have the answer ready at hand ;)

Thanks

Comment: Only mention of C# is in the title and tags. Are you using C# or C?

Comment: @Yuvi, My guess is that he wants to listen to an "event" in C# that is fired in another application not in his "domain".

Comment: @Yuvi I mention C# as my base program is written in C#. Not really comfortable to use C++ for Business apps ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on Chris Taylor's answer: Instead of doing the native interop yourself, you can use [ManagedWinApi](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/), which contains a `Hook` class.

EDIT: To use ManagedWinApi. Somewhere in your code:

```
Hook MyHook = new Hook(HookType.WH_CALLWNDPROC, false, false);
MyHook.Callback += MyHookCallback;
MyHook StartHook();
```

For the callback, reference [CallWndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644975.aspx) and [CWPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644964.aspx):

```
private static int MyHookCallback(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool callNext)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        // You will need to define the struct
        var message = (CWPSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPSTRUCT));
        // Do something with the data
    }
    return 0; // Return value is ignored unless you set callNext to false
}
```

Comment: Indeed I stumbled upon ManagedWinAPi but the docs are not as self-explaining as I'd love too, seen my incompetence in the WinAPI. I am looking into the examples to get it.

As far as I have understood, I do not really need a global system hoow as a direct hook to the window is sufficient. I just need to be notified about the resize/move events. Ideally this should happen in a C# event.

What I need to figure out is how to connect the dots, therefore any suggestion is more than welcome, especially from people familiar with the ManagedWinApi.

Comment: Thanks! That is very much clarifying. I will test it asap. For reference, CWPSTRUCT is here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CWPSTRUCT.html

Comment: your suggested code hooks only to windows inside the C# project. I need to hook to an external window. Googling around I understood that this seems not possible in C#, unless Magadewinapi has a way to do this. I tried to set the global param in the Hook constructor to true, but I banged my session. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Steve The hook is for windows in the same application (they don't have to be C#-windows). As for cross-process hooks, I'm not sure exactly how this works together with "global" (didn't need it so far). You might also have problems in newer Windows-versions due to security...

Comment: @SteveVedovelli Did any other answer work for you? I'm looking for the same thing as you- hook to an external window to handle when it gets resized.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same thing in some code I was working with and discovered I couldn't inject a managed .DLL into the process.

Not wanting to write a C++ unmanaged DLL that used SetWindowsHook, I went with a combination of `SetWinEventHook`, which signals when a window starts and ends a move event and a `Timer` to poll the window while it's moving to give it the appearance of following the window while it moves.

Here's a (very simplified) version of a class that can do that (just replace the TODO's with code to move the window or raise an event).

```
public class DockingHelper
{
    private readonly uint m_processId, m_threadId;

    private readonly IntPtr m_target;

    // Needed to prevent the GC from sweeping up our callback
    private readonly WinEventDelegate m_winEventDelegate;
    private IntPtr m_hook;

    private Timer m_timer;

    public DockingHelper(string windowName, string className)
    {
        if (windowName == null && className == null) throw new ArgumentException("Either windowName or className must have a value");

        m_target = FindWindow(className, windowName);
        ThrowOnWin32Error("Failed to get target window");

        m_threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(m_target, out m_processId);
        ThrowOnWin32Error("Failed to get process id");

        m_winEventDelegate = WhenWindowMoveStartsOrEnds;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    private void ThrowOnWin32Error(string message)
    {
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (err != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(err, message);
    }

    private RECT GetWindowLocation()
    {
        RECT loc;
        GetWindowRect(m_target, out loc);
        if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
        {
            // Do something useful with this to handle if the target window closes, etc.
        }
        return loc;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // 10 = window move start, 11 = window move end, 0 = fire out of context
        m_hook = SetWinEventHook(10, 11, m_target, m_winEventDelegate, m_processId, m_threadId, 0);
    }

    private void PollWindowLocation(object state)
    {
        var location = GetWindowLocation();
        // TODO: Reposition your window with the values from location (or fire an event with it attached)
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        UnhookWinEvent(m_hook);
    }

    private void WhenWindowMoveStartsOrEnds(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
    {
        if (hwnd != m_target) // We only want events from our target window, not other windows owned by the thread.
            return;

        if (eventType == 10) // Starts
        {
            m_timer = new Timer(PollWindowLocation, null, 10, Timeout.Infinite);
            // This is always the original position of the window, so we don't need to do anything, yet.
        }
        else if (eventType == 11)
        {
            m_timer.Dispose();
            m_timer = null;
            var location = GetWindowLocation();
            // TODO: Reposition your window with the values from location (or fire an event with it attached)
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }

    private delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);
}
```

Comment: Very user-friendly sharing! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

A [`WH_CALLWNDPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) hook would probably suffice, this will allow you to monitor all messages destined for the window of interest.

Are you asking how to create a global hook using C# or are you happy to create the hook in C++ and then interop with that from .NET? The second option is the route I would go.

Basically off the top of my head, what I would do is the following

1- Create global hook in C, and export functions to `InstallHook` and `UninstallHook`, which can be called from your C# app using Interop. InstallHook take an hwnd of the window in your C# application.

2- Have the installed hook function post a custom message to the C# window provided in the call to `InstallHook` when ever there is a message you are interested in like `WM_SIZE` in your case.

3- In the C# application your window that receives the posted messages from the hook will override [WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc.aspx) to handle the custom message.

That is an outline of one approach.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use WinEvents:

```
public delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess, uint idThread, uint dwFlags);
```

See also:[event hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665579/setting-up-hook-on-windows-messages?lq=1)

Comment: I am sure this works. I just wrote a program taking advantages of SetWinEventHook.