# How to receive the windows messages of an unmanaged Win32 and Win64 app in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged app both in 32 bit and 64 bit on Windows 7 64.

I want to write a C# application to receive the keyboard messages it's receiving, so I could do certain things on certain key presses, and for others, simply send it back to the app, so as not to interfere with them.

I don't know the right way to search for this so not sure how this would be done.

Also I want to avoid using keyboard hooks if possible. Just want to receive the app's keyboard messages is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what keyboard hooks are designed for.  There aren't any alternatives that don't have all the problems of keyboard hooks (and probably some additional ones).

Comment: Thanks but someone told me I could just hook into the app's message pump and interpret them, and another problem is the keyboard hooks (low level) that I had to use had to be global so had to make it filter all other key presses except if they are coming from my app.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about injecting a DLL and subclassing.  This is (1) not easy with .NET and (2) more destabilizing than keyboard hooks.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading here, basically want to do something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880160/listening-to-another-window-resize-events-in-c So is it still DLL injecting and subclassing? The second answer suggests to use WH_CALLWNDPROC to create a hook for the app that's not global. Is this possible? What do you think?

Comment: There definitely are advantages to installing a per-thread hook instead of a global hook... but [keyboard hooks can also be set per-thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880160/listening-to-another-window-resize-events-in-c) about adding hooks to specific windows. I've no idea how to read the message pump of other apps. You can do it with a IMessageFilter but it only will work in the current app...