# handle native external process windows events from c#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, events, process

I'm starting a process (namely gnuplot.exe) from within a C# application. 
The process can open some window and for that process i'd like to intercept the events of:

- opened window
- closed window
- focused window

The basic idea is to handle if the user closes some windows or changes the active window and so on, referring only to the started process. In other word, i don't want to handle others focus changes or closed windows events which are not thrown by a gnuplot window.

Can you help me? Is it possible to avoid polling? Which api should i refer to? Can you paste/link an mwe or some example code?
Thank you in advance

**Update**

As suggested by Eric Brown I tried this way, but still not works. Can you help me to detect where am I wrong?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Automation;

    namespace WinApiEvents
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Process gp = new Process();
                gp.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Software\gp463-win32\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe";
                gp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                gp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                gp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                gp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                gp.Start();

                AutomationElement targetElement = 
                    AutomationElement.FromHandle(gp.Handle);

                StructureChangedEventHandler structChangedHandler =
                    new StructureChangedEventHandler(OnGnuplotWindowStructureChanged);
                Automation.AddStructureChangedEventHandler(
                    targetElement, TreeScope.Element, structChangedHandler);

                AutomationEventHandler focusHandler =
                    new AutomationEventHandler(OnGnuplotWindowFocusGained);
                Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
                    AutomationElement.AutomationFocusChangedEvent, targetElement, TreeScope.Element, focusHandler);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("set term wxt 1 enhanced");
                sb.AppendLine("plot sin(x)");
                gp.StandardInput.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                gp.StandardInput.Flush();
                                    sb.Clear();


                sb.AppendLine("set term wxt 2 enhanced");
                sb.AppendLine("plot cos(x)");
                gp.StandardInput.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                gp.StandardInput.Flush();
                                    sb.Clear();


                sb.AppendLine("set term wxt 3 enhanced");
                sb.AppendLine("plot atan(x)");
                gp.StandardInput.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                gp.StandardInput.Flush();
                                    sb.Clear();

                MessageBox.Show("Click to exit.");

            }

            private static void OnGnuplotWindowStructureChanged(object src, StructureChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("structure changed window, id=" + e.EventId.ProgrammaticName);
            }

            private static void OnGnuplotWindowFocusGained(object src, AutomationEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("focused window, id=" + e.EventId.ProgrammaticName);
            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Similar Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880160/listening-to-another-window-resize-events-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Same idea, use a WH_SHELL hook for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework for this.

I assume you have (or can get) the gnuplot window handle.  Once you have that, you can get the [UI Automation element for that window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.fromhandle.aspx), and set up [FocusChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationfocuschangedevent.aspx) event handlers, and [StructureChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automation.addstructurechangedeventhandler.aspx) handlers to detect subwindow opening & closing.  The [WindowClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowclosedevent.aspx) event will tell you if the gnuplot window itself closes.  (You can use this on subwindows as well, but you'll still need to listen for StructureChanged events to detect subwindow open events.)