# Getting a separate application to reconize it was resized

Tags: c#, winapi, unmanaged

I have a separate game I am running and I resize it down to the size of a portion of my C# project form. Works exactly how I want it to except the game does not recognize that it has been resized. So all the control inputs are a bit off and the UI scale is off. The strange thing is if I manually resize or move the game window, everything fixes itself.

Tried `SendMessage()`and `Invalidate()`, min and maxing the window, without much luck. Here is what I currently have.

```
Process firstGame = Process.GetProcessesByName("gameprocessname").ElementAt(0); 

if (firstGame != null)
{
    try
    { 
        IntPtr firstGameHandle = firstGame.MainWindowHandle; //get handle of game win
        IntPtr mainFormHandle = this.Handle; // store handle of my app
        SetWindowLong(firstGameHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER); // get rid of borders

        // move the window where we want
        SetWindowPos(
            firstGameHandle, (IntPtr)0, gb.Location.X, gb.Location.Y, gb.Width, gb.Height,
            SHOWWINDOW);

        // make my application parent of the game
        SetParent(firstGameHandle, mainFormHandle);

        // child handle was lost on SetParent(); get Game handle again
        IntPtr childHandle = FindWindowEx(
            this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "gamewndclass", "titlecaption");
        SetWindowText(childHandle, gameTitle); //Rename gamewindow
        SetForegroundWindow(childHandle); //set game window as active
        boxhandle = childHandle; //store the game windows handle

        // last thing I tried to get window to redraw and reset
        RedrawWindow(
            this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
            RedrawWindowFlags.Frame |
                RedrawWindowFlags.UpdateNow |
                RedrawWindowFlags.Invalidate);
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + er.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This involves using hooks. Look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880160/listening-to-another-window-resize-events-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Its a start I think, pointed me in a new direction at least. Thank you.

Comment: This is similar. Not really looking for when the even goes off as to more how to trigger it. For some reason the window resizes fine border wise but the content or the game window scaling doesn't get ready to the new window size. Scaling the window manually or moving it by the titlebar seems to get the content to reset. I am just trying to get my program to trigger the same call on the game window that happens when a user resizes the window manually.  Sorry if this seems convoluted